# App keeps running even after "killed"

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-intent, android-resources

My app (or at least parts of it) keeps running even after it is "killed" (swiped and\or after the "clear all apps" button).

On the main activity (which contains fragments), I'm overriding onBackPressed (EDIT: the overriding is done to first of all ask the user if he\she wants to get out of the system, and only *then* use the below function, in case they chose to exit) to do this:

```
public void exit()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

1. When I'm exiting the app the usual way (with the "exit" method above), and then re-enter the app, the app will re-open and will continue from where it stopped (with the last visible fragment appearing).
2. When I'm trying to either kill the app through the device's "recent applications" screen (maybe it doesn't really kill it?), or to re-compile without exiting the app for debugging purposes, I'm getting a blank black screen instead of getting to the Splash Screen... which makes me suspect some parts of the app are still running in the background. Also, around every few minutes, I'm getting the message: " isn't responding. Do you want to close it?"

My question(s):

1. Isn't this line supposed to kill all activities (including their fragments)? Or do I have to use the finish() method? (Not that it's a bad thing, I'm just wondering why the activity didn't get killed).

   ```
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   ```
2. Why would the app keep running even after I tried to kill it? And how do I make sure it is completely killed?

Comment: Have you used finish() after starting the activity ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Intent.ACTION_MAIN means this activity will run first when you open your application, this is the entry point of the app.
2. Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP when you have multiple activities and opening one by one and if you want to go to some previous activity then you can use this intent.
3. finish() it will finish the current activity and your application will start from MainActivity() if its not minimized.

Answer (score 1):

First: If you want to close the current `Activity` use this:

```
public void exit()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);

    finish(); // <-- this added
}
```

Second: I dont know why you want to use this exit method (since the standard back functionallity finishes the top activity) but `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` is used for:

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

For `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

> If set, this activity will become the start of a new task on this history stack.

Try to use this: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`:

> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to be cleared before the activity is started. That is, the activity becomes the new root of an otherwise empty task, and any old activities are finished. This can only be used in conjunction with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

```
public void exit()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // <-- this changed
    startActivity(intent);

    finish(); // <-- this added
}
```

For your second question: If you kill your app the app must be killed. It can be possible that you have a background service running which starts the app again using an intent but if not the app should not be running after the kill.

Maybe check your entry point of the app (your `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />`) activity and check if it is receiving any intents or if any other activity is receiving intents.

**EDIT**

This is a common way to make the user press the back button twice before exiting the app. Simply add this to your `Activity`:

```
private static final int TIME_INTERVAL = 2000;
private Handler backHandler = null;
boolean exit = false;

...


/**
 * 
 */
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if(this.backHandler != null) {
        this.backHandler.removeCallbacks(this.backRunnable);
    }
}

/**
 * 
 */
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(this.exit) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }

    this.exit = true;

    Toast.makeText(this, this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_exit), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    this.backHandler = new Handler();
    this.backHandler.postDelayed(this.backRunnable, TIME_INTERVAL);
}

/**
 * 
 */
private final Runnable backRunnable = new Runnable() {
    /**
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        exit = false;   
        backHandler = null;
    }
};
```

In the following example when the user presses the back button in the homescreen a toast pops up with a message. If the user presses the back button again within the given time interval the app closes.

Comment: 1. Thanks for your answer, it explains a lot
2. The reason  i'm using that function, is that the onBackPressed overriding is used for asking the user if he\she wants to exit first
3. I knew adding finish() would kill the activity and I'm happy with the way things are right now (well, at least about case #1), I just misunderstood the flags themselves (For some reason i was convinced they are supposed to do that, and don't).
4. About killing the app - i guess i should make a more thorough investigation of the intents...

Comment: Updated my post to show a common way how to override the back button functionality to not instantyl exit the app on first use of the back button in the home screen.